# DialogFlow Actions-on-google : Unable to complete the account linking through the google home app

Tags: authentication, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

In account linking process for actions-on-google I am able to do account linking only through the simulator but not from the card i receive in the google home app.
it would be great, if any one can suggest what might be the issue.

I have attached the screen shots below.

When clicked on the link button the screen fades and no action is performed.

[Before Clicking on the link button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2gJv.png)

[After clicking on the link button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgl8Z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for the problem.
The issue was the device language was set as "English India" And the card was generated for "English US". When I matched the language settings in both developer console and my device settings. It worked fine.
Account linking work well now.